# How to make an image border in Sketch Flow 4?

Tags: xaml, sketchflow

I am using Expression Blend + Sketch Flow 4

How to make the image box to have a border?

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Border = "2" Margin="60,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

I have try the XAML code with border = "2" 
But is not working. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your `Image` with a `Border`. :)

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" ... >
    <Image ... />
</Border>
```

Comment: o. Too bad. 
Mean the original image won't hv the function of border?

Comment: No, unfortunately `Image` doesn't support that.